# What is the difference between writing jquery.fn.colorbox and jQuery.colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

When i write `jQuery.fn.colorbox()` it gives me same results as `jQuery.colorbox();` I want to understand the significance of `fn` in jQuery.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time I looked, fn was an alias for prototype in jquery.

Take a look at [this stackexchange answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310870/use-of-prototype-vs-this-in-javascript), it may give you some clarity.